# Initial selection not highlighted in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, selection, highlighting

I have been searching for days trying to find why I cannot get a simple ListView to highlight an initial selection -- just as though the selection has been touched.  I have read through the discussions on Touch Mode and still cannot find a solution.

A simple version of my code is:

```
public class TestList extends Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.listmain);  
    // Layout contains just a ListView with id list
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    String[] values = new String[] {"Android","iPhone","WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X","Linux","OS/2"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    listView.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);

    listView.requestFocusFromTouch();

    listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.setSelection(2);
        }
    });

  }
}
```

The resulting ListView should show Item 2 (WindowsMobile) highlighted, but does not.  It I touch the item, it remains highlighted, as I want.  I have tried all of the standard simple_list layout forms, functions such as setFocusable(true), setFocusableInTouchMode(true), setItemChecked(2,true), performItemClick() -- before or after the setSelection() call -- but all to no avail.
If I try to set the highlighted item in GetView(), the ability for the user to select a different item is lost.
Can anyone tell me how to programatically set the initial highlighted item without disabling the ability for the user to change the selection?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#FFCC00"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem arises from the fact that ListView Selectors don't work as they should.  For example, I have discovered that, if I use a selector with a white background, my initial selection will be highlighted, but just change the color to something other than white and it does not work!

So code is changed to:

```
listView.setSelector(R.drawable.selector);
```

and selector.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light" android:state_selected="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" android:state_activated="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

I have tried various Selectors, including separate Selectors for the background.  Some work, some don't.  Some work when the apk is first loaded, but don't work when the app is run again.